# The Fricke involution on arbitrary subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\textbf{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\textbf{Z})$. I want to understand how the Fricke involution $w_N : f \longrightarrow (\tau \longrightarrow N^{-k/2}\tau^{-k}f(-1/N\tau))$ acts on the space $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$.

Since 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1/N \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} d & -c/N \\ -bN & a  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1/N \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$
it seems that if we introduce the subgroup
$$\Gamma_N:=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma \quad , \quad \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix} \pmod N \right\}$$
then $w_Nf$ is invariant under the usual transformation of weight $k$ on $\Gamma_N$ (if $f$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma)$). But under which conditions can we conclude that $w_Nf$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma_N)$ ? Is that true for all $N$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why $w_N$ should act on $M_k(\Gamma)$ for a general subgroup $\Gamma$. The action will make sense if, and only if, we have
$$\Gamma = w_N^{-1} \Gamma w_N,$$
which is true if $\Gamma_1(N) \subseteq \Gamma \subseteq \Gamma_0(N)$ and false for most other subgroups. (E.g. it's clearly false for $\Gamma = \Gamma_1(MN)$ for $M > 1$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The term 'act' was in fact not really appropriated... I was rather thinking of $\Gamma_N$ defined as (following your notation) $\Gamma=w_N^{-1} \Gamma_N w_N$ and I was wondering if an integer $N$ exists such that $w_N : \mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma) \longrightarrow \mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma_N)$. (I hope that I haven't misunderstood something...)

Comment: If you *define* $\Gamma_N$ as $w_N^{-1} \Gamma w_N$, then $w_N$ will give a map (indeed a bijection) $M_k(\Gamma) \to M_k(\Gamma_N)$ (for any $N$ and $\Gamma$). Is that what you were after?

Comment: Sorry for the wait, and thanks for your answer : yes that is what I was looking for.